# To run all tests in Visual studio Code Sandbox:

Tags: vs-code

I'm not able to see the Invoke apex tests option in ctrl+shift+P, do I need to download any additional extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage" to 'true' in set in vscode settings.json